# Creating a new column based on conditions for other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with columns consisting of some values and NaN where there were no values assigned for the specific column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [10, 46, 75, 12, 99, 84],
                   'col1': ['Nan',         
                            15,
                            'Nan',
                            14,
                            'NaN',
                            'NaN'],
                   'col2': ['NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 12, 876, 4452],
                   'col3': ['NaN', 11, 13, 546, 9897, 1]
                                   })
                                
df
```

With the following output:

```
id  col1    col2    col3
0   10  Nan NaN NaN
1   46  15  NaN 11
2   75  Nan NaN 13
3   12  14  12  546
4   99  NaN 876 9897
5   84  NaN 4452  1
```

My objective is to create a new column (col4), which says 'original' for all the rows where all three columns (col1, col2, col3) have NaN and 'referenced' otherwise.
I tried the np.where method (given below), but it doesn't work as 'NaN' is (probably) not picked up as a numerical value.

```
df['col4'] = np.where((df['col1'] == 'NaN') & (df['col2'] == 'NaN') & (df['col3'] == 'NaN'), 'original', 'referenced')
```

I am not that advanced in Python and cannot think of what the alternative should be.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Are these actual nans or just strings `"NaN"`?

Comment: The expected output should be: col4 = 'original' for row1 and 'referenced' for all other rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) for test all columns if missing and then [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all Trues per rows:

```
#If necessary
import numpy as np

df  = df.replace(['Nan', 'NaN'], np.nan)

df['col4'] = np.where(df[['col1','col2','col3']].isna().all(1), 'original', 'referenced')
```

Your solution with [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
df['col4'] = np.where(df['col1'].isna() & df['col2'].isna() & df['col3'].isna(), 
                     'original', 'referenced')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the string `NaN` or `Nan` first

```py
df = df.replace('(?i)nan', 'NaN', regex=True)
df['col4'] = np.where(df.filter(like='col').eq('NaN').all(axis=1), 'original', 'referenced')

# or

df = df.replace('(?i)nan', pd.NA, regex=True)
df['col4'] = np.where(df.filter(like='col').isna().all(axis=1), 'original', 'referenced')
```

```
print(df)

   id col1  col2  col3        col4
0  10  NaN   NaN   NaN    original
1  46   15   NaN    11  referenced
2  75  NaN   NaN    13  referenced
3  12   14    12   546  referenced
4  99  NaN   876  9897  referenced
5  84  NaN  4452     1  referenced
```

Comment: For some reason, when I apply this code, I get 'referenced' for row 1 as well.